# Is there an iOS SDK of Alchemy API?

Tags: ibm-cloud, alchemyapi

is there a software development kit (sdk) for AlchemyAPI using Swift/Objective-C  for iOS native developer?

Comment: I have submitted a Bluemix idea on your behalf at the following URL: http://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas/suggestions/11579868-provide-a-sdk-for-alchemyapi-using-swift-objective

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Watson iOS SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk) now includes wrappers for the AlchemyLanguage and AlchemyVision services.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not at is time. Seems like an odd omission considering how many others they have.

http://www.alchemyapi.com/developers/sdks

Comment: Thank you for your response, currently it has other version of Alchemy API, but it is nice to have an iOS version API or framework, I think.